# Most likely coin given a bag of coins

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random

Suppose I have a bag of $n$ biased coins, and I sample without replacement $m < n$ of them, and measure each coin $i$ for their parameter $p_i \in [0,1]$, that is each coin is $Bernoulli(p_i)$. Now I would like to ask what is the most likely $p_{m+1}$ on the next coin I pick. I am not sure how to answer this question aside from taking the mean of all $m$ coins' parameter so far. That is: $\hat{p}_{m+1} = \frac{p_1 + \ldots + p_m}{m}$.

However I cannot prove why this is the most likely $p$. Any thoughts?

Comment: What does $p$ represent?  The probability of...what?  Or is it just some parameter whose physical significance we don't care about?  And is it significant that the coins are bent?

Comment: so the coins are $Bernoulli(p)$, so $p$ is the probability of getting head. By bent I mean the coins are biased, each one with a different bias.

Comment: OK.  You probably should say "biased" instead of "bent"; I would take a bent coin to refer to one that is physically bent (like, say, a taco).  And edit the question so that you make it clear that $p$ is the probability of getting heads (you never say anything about flipping the coins!), and that each coin has a different value of $p$. Otherwise, the question as it is currently is hopelessly vague.  Finally, how do you measure their $p$?

Comment: ok added the comments. You can assume their $p$ is given. Or you toss each 100 times and estimate it. Does it make a difference?

Comment: It might.  Do we have any information about how the $p_i$ are distributed?  Are they drawn, say, from a uniform distribution over $[0, 1]$?  Beta?  Or could it be anything?

Comment: are you asking for the prior distribution? Beta looks appropriate here.